# How to figure out how many times a function has been uniquely called

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript and trying to learn from the beginning.
I have a script where I can do two different calculations using radio buttons, area and circumference.
I want to display how many times people have counted out different calculations.
If I use to show clicks on button then it counts everything together, but how can I separate them?

```
document.getElementById("calculate").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var button = document.getElementById("calculate");
  var x, text;
  x = document.getElementById("radius").value;
  if (document.getElementById("area").checked) {
    if (isNaN(x) || x < 1 || x > 100) {
      text = "Fel radie";
      document.getElementById('radius').value = '';
    } else {
      let radius = document.getElementById("radius").value;
      area = Math.PI * radius * radius;
    }
    if (document.getElementById("areaoutput").innerHTML = text);
    else(document.getElementById("areaoutput").innerHTML = "Area = " + area);
  }


  if (document.getElementById("circumference").checked) {
    let radius = document.getElementById("radius").value;
    if (isNaN(x) || x < 1 || x > 100) {
      text = "Fel radie";
      document.getElementById('radius').value = '';
    } else {
      let radius = document.getElementById("radius").value;
      circumference = Math.PI * 2 * radius;
    }
    if (document.getElementById("circoutput").innerHTML = text);
    else(document.getElementById("circoutput").innerHTML = "Circumference = " + circumference);
  }
  if (document.getElementById("area").checked) {
    var count = localStorage.on_load_counter || 0;
    var button = document.getElementById("calculate");
    var display = document.getElementById("areacount");

    button.onclick = function() {
      localStorage.on_load_counter = display.innerHTML = ++count;
    }
  }
  if (document.getElementById("circumference").checked) {
    var count = localStorage.on_load_counter || 0;
    var button = document.getElementById("calculate");
    var display = document.getElementById("circcount");
  }
  button.onclick = function() {
    localStorage.on_load_counter = display.innerHTML = ++count;
  }

}, false);
```

Comment: Please fix the indentation so that we can more easily understand what your code is doing.

Comment: `if (a = b); else (a = c);` does not seem like it will do what you expect it to.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing something like this

`var combinationsDone = [];`

Then every time the user does a calculation, you would add an object to `combinationsDone`.

For example, if they have a radius of 5, and circumference isn't checked, this is what you should do.

```
var combination = {
    radius: 5,
    circumference: false
}

if(!combinationsDone.includes(combination)){
    combinationsDone.push(combination);
}
```

What this does is it makes sure that the combination wasn't recorded previously before adding the combination. Then, when you want to get the number of different combinations they have done, just user `combinationsDone.length`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a global variable. which is increased every time you call the function.

```
var myFuncCalls = 0;

function myFunction()
{
    myFuncCalls++;
    alert( "I have been called " + myFuncCalls + " times" );
}
```